# LoginStatus won't change status after a successful login - asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing a website now as a college project but the loginstatus won't change as I login successfully.

It's placed on the master page (since I want it to be viewed at all times and on all pages) but it just will not change it's status to logout.

Also after logging in only the page is directed to a welcome (username) page but after that it will go back to no user as if no one has logged in ever and I'm just a random site visitor. (Note that even at the (welcome [username]) page the status is still login.)

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config file add :

```html
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="#" timeout="60" />
</authentication>
```

and after check username and password add this code :

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
```